# Drawing Hasse diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I am trying to draw a Hasse diagram for
Set {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(4,5),(5,5)}
I drew a diagram like this. But I am not sure about the positioning number(level) and my diagram. Can you check and give me some advice?

[here my diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olte4.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: As an aside, it is largely irrelevant whether or not the $2$ and $3$ are at the same "height" as the $4$ versus if they are instead at the same "height" as the $5$.  There is benefit to either choice.  Do whatever is more comfortable to you.